# Spring State Machine Asynchronous Processes

Tags: spring-rabbit, spring-statemachine

I am trying to solving a problem where the spring state machine have actions which invoke external long running processes via RabbitMQ. Here are the steps:

1. A state machine event is issued
2. The associated Action send a message to an external microservice via RabbitMQ
3. The external microservice takes 1 hour to process the request and send the response back to the State machine
4. The state machine picks up the message and update the state.

The issue I am having is how to block the state machine and wait for the response from that remote service before updating the state. I would greatly appreciate any help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

You do not need explicit blocking of the state machine.
The machine will remain in the same target state (pre step 1) unless the next event (in your case response from the long running process is received), for that instance of a machine.

If to track, you can have another intermediate state "WAITINGFORMESSAGE", and transition from this stage to the next stage on receiving of message.